# Symfony Webpack use simple function

Tags: symfony, webpack

I was wondering how to use a simple function using Symfony + Webpack + Encore.

I have my file `accentsDelete.js` with :

```
export default function accentsDelete(string) {
   ...
}
```

And in my `app.js` file :

```
import accentsDeletefrom './accentsDelete';
```

But I still get the error when I try to use `accentsDelete('éléphant')` in my Twig templates :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: accentsDeleteis not defined

My Webpack config is almost the original one, do I need to specify a scope or something ?

Comment: Your file is called `accentRemove.js`, but you import from `accentsDelete(.js)`. Also you have a syntax error in your code example.

Comment: Yes just misspelling in the question

Comment: Please correct the code examples and the error to reflect exactly your working environment.